# building a simple Sudoku print in python

Tags: python

What i'm trying to do is write a code in python which will print a simple Sudoku (solved for now).
I started with a 4 on 4, but planing on 9 on 9 after that.

I managed to make the numbers to not repeat other numbers horizontal and vertical, the problem is how to make them not repeat other numbers within their "box".

Example:

```
4 3 2 1  
3 2 1 4  
1 4 3 2  
2 1 4 3
```

Expected:

```
4 3 2 1  
2 1 4 3  
1 4 3 2  
3 2 1 4
```

Code:

```
import random

# preforming 1st check if the giving number already exist in the list sq
# which is created in main

def chk1(num):
    while num in sq:
        num = random.randint(1,4)
    return num

# preforming 2nd check if the giving number already exist in the current index
# of each list that is in sud which is created in main

def chk2(num, i, y):
    x = 0
    curr = 0

    while x != i:
        if num != sud[curr][y]:
            x +=1
            curr +=1
        else:
            num = random.randint(1,4)
            x = 0
            curr = 0
    return num

# creating the structure of 4 lists in the list sud using the 1st & 2nd check
# each round a unique list is created and is appended to anther list.   

def main():
    global sq, sud
    curry = 0
    currx = 0
    sq = []
    sud = []

    for i in range(4):

        for y in range(4):

            num = random.randint(1,4)
            num = chk1(num)
            if curry == 1 & currx == 1:
                num = chk2(num, i, y)
            sq.append(num)
            if curry == 0:
                curry +=1
        sud.append(sq)
        if currx == 0:
            currx +=1
        sq = []

    return sud

# printing the final output of main function by line

for line in main():
    print(line)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your cryptic variable and function names and the complete lack of comments makes your code pretty incoimprehensible - can I suggest that if you want to ask for help you make your code more helpable?

Comment: It's not at all obvious from reading your code how you intend for your algorithm to work, especially since you used global variables. You will need to explain in words what your algorithm is doing, otherwise you are asking us to try to reverse-engineer your code.

Comment: yes, i'm aware of that fact, i thought it will be easy enough to understand, guess i was wrong.

Comment: I highly suggest you improve your question about what your are asking and what is your problem, it isn't clear. Plus, take a look at [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and [PEP-20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Answer (score 0):

Your code may get stuck if it generates a partial set of incompatible numbers. Try this one - it uses recursion and steps back if fails to place another digit:

```
import numpy as np

def build_sudoku(sudoku=None, i=None):
    if sudoku is None:
        sudoku = np.zeros((9, 9), dtype=int)
        i = 80
    if i < 0:
        return sudoku

    s = sudoku.copy()
    r, c = i // 9,  i % 9
    row, col = s[r, :], s[:, c]
    square = g[r//3 * 3:r//3 * 3+3, c//3 * 3:c//3 * 3+3].flatten()
    valid = [v for v in np.arange(1, 10) if v not in set([*row, *col, *square])]

    np.random.shuffle(valid)
    for v in valid:
        s[r, c] = v
        result = fill_one(s, i-1)
        if result is not None:
            return result
    return None

build_sudoku()

array([[3, 1, 5, 8, 4, 2, 9, 7, 6],
       [2, 8, 7, 5, 9, 6, 3, 4, 1],
       [9, 4, 6, 1, 7, 3, 2, 8, 5],
       [5, 6, 4, 7, 2, 8, 1, 9, 3],
       [7, 9, 1, 3, 5, 4, 8, 6, 2],
       [8, 2, 3, 6, 1, 9, 4, 5, 7],
       [6, 3, 2, 9, 8, 7, 5, 1, 4],
       [1, 7, 8, 4, 3, 5, 6, 2, 9],
       [4, 5, 9, 2, 6, 1, 7, 3, 8]])
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem you've presented is much nearer to the Magic Square problem then the actual sudoku (sum of rows, sum of columns + sum in small squares). Therefore, I am providing you example of magic square implementation example from [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/magic-square/):

```
def generateSquare(n): 

    # 2-D array with all 
    # slots set to 0 
    magicSquare = [[0 for x in range(n)] 
                    for y in range(n)] 

    # initialize position of 1 
    i = n / 2
    j = n - 1

    # Fill the magic square 
    # by placing values 
    num = 1
    while num <= (n * n): 
        if i == -1 and j == n: # 3rd condition 
            j = n - 2
            i = 0
        else: 

            # next number goes out of 
            # right side of square 
            if j == n: 
                j = 0

            # next number goes 
            # out of upper side 
            if i < 0: 
                i = n - 1

        if magicSquare[int(i)][int(j)]: # 2nd condition 
            j = j - 2
            i = i + 1
            continue
        else: 
            magicSquare[int(i)][int(j)] = num 
            num = num + 1

        j = j + 1
        i = i - 1 # 1st condition 


    # Printing magic square 
    print ("Magic Squre for n =", n) 
    print ("Sum of each row or column", 
            n * (n * n + 1) / 2, "\n") 

    for i in range(0, n): 
        for j in range(0, n): 
            print('%2d ' % (magicSquare[i][j]), 
                                    end = '') 

            # To display output 
            # in matrix form 
            if j == n - 1: 
                print() 

n = 7
generateSquare(n)
```

Comment: I think you mean [Latin square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square), not [magic square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square). This answer is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Nope, I am exactly referring to the magic square, since it is the simplification of sudoku problem. Magic square is common task in math competitions for elementary schools. And yes, this answer IS relevant to the question :)

Comment: The OP's example of expected output is very clearly not a magic square, and magic squares are not at all a "simplification" of sudokus. A 4x4 magic square uses the numbers from 1 to 16, a Latin square uses the numbers 1 to 4 four times each.

Comment: I support kaya3 : Latin square is about uniqueness (which is what we need in Sudoku), and magic square is about constant sums...

Comment: I guess we're not on the same page out here in understanding OPs needs. Ill leave this answer until more proper one is published and accepted, then ill delete it :)